# Google Calendar API: TimeZone not taken into account by google server?

Tags: rest, timezone, google-calendar-api

I am playing around with the google calendar programmatic interface at:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it

When I execute the following request I get the following response:

Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/o38t4tnqifv4kdanjkmegs2uqk%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZRv_qi4OhIhzN1C8YifUSO4mmXjufeKhaPmbyaRw3FVhXIgJQ
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
"end": {
"dateTime": "2013-04-07T20:30:00.01Z"
},
"start": {
"dateTime": "2013-04-07T19:30:00.01Z"
},
"description": "Just testing, 2003.",
"extendedProperties": {
"private": {
"foo": "bar"
}
},
"summary": "Hello World 1"
}
```

Response:

```
200 OK

- Show headers -
{
"kind": "calendar#event",
"etag": "\"78Bu1G8fWt0vPGZK2Ckfad3ZtNE/Z2NhbDAwMDAxMzY4NzE0MzM1NTc3MDAw\"",
"id": "e2pfv3men0e9r5mv4qp7hrsqs8",
"status": "confirmed",
"htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ZTJwZnYzbWVuMGU5cjVtdjRxcDdocnNxczggbzM4dDR0bnFpZnY0a2RhbmprbWVnczJ1cWtAZw",
"created": "2013-05-16T14:25:35.000Z",
"updated": "2013-05-16T14:25:35.577Z",
"summary": "Hello World 1",
"description": "Just testing, 2003.",
"creator": {
"email": "jdoe@gmail.com"
},
"organizer": {
"email": "o38t4tnqifv4kdanjkmegs2uqk@group.calendar.google.com",
"displayName": "ClientEventManager",
"self": true
},
"start": {
"dateTime": "2013-04-07T19:30:00Z"
},
"end": {
"dateTime": "2013-04-07T20:30:00Z"
},
"iCalUID": "e2pfv3men0e9r5mv4qp7hrsqs8@google.com",
"sequence": 0,
"extendedProperties": {
"private": {
"foo": "bar"
}
},
"reminders": {
"useDefault": true
}
}
```

I thought the .01Z at the end of the DateTime entries would specify
the +01 time zone (European Central Time), but instead it seems that
the google server just ignores it and converts it to GMT (one hour
difference) without adding 1 to the hours, displaying the event
as taking place one hour outside of when specified.
In particular notice:

Request:

```
{
"end": {
"dateTime": "2013-04-07T20:30:00.01Z"
},
"start": {
"dateTime": "2013-04-07T19:30:00.01Z"
},
```

Response:

```
"start": {
"dateTime": "2013-04-07T19:30:00Z"
},
"end": {
"dateTime": "2013-04-07T20:30:00Z"
},
```

Google just turned the .01Z into .00Z without chanight 19:30 to 20:30
and 20:30 to 21:30. What's up here? Have I got the syntax wrong? If so then how?

Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Google API is disregarding time zone. I am passing "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles" and the time is still being converted into GMT by Google.

Answer (score 0):

The API accepts a 'timeZone' parameter. You might want to try passing a timezone value like 'GMT+1:00' or 'UTC+1:00'.

We had a similar problem in our team before and we just played around with the values to get things right.

Comment: I am doing that but still the events returned have the same if I set the timezone to "GMT+1:00", to "GMT+1", to "GMT" to "Europe/London" or even if I don't set it at all. They are all US West Coast time, which is for some reason the timezone of the calendar. Am I missing the purpose of that input parameter or is it being ignored?

Comment: Have you tried removing the .01Z or .00Z? It has been awhile, but if I'm recalling things right, Z indicates Zulu Time or what is commonly  known as GMT. That's probably why you are still getting GMT results.

Comment: Thanks for this. However removing the "Z" or adding a ".00Z" or a ".06Z" or other similar things all yielded the same results...

Answer (score 0):

The `.01Z` part in `2013-04-07T20:30:00.01Z` is **not** a time zone offset. The `01` defines the number of milliseconds (in this case 10 milliseconds). The character `Z` defines the actual time zone (UTC, also known as Zulu, in this case).

If you want to define the time zone offset as +01, the format to use is most certainly `+01:00`. So your example would instead be `2013-04-07T20:30:00+01:00`.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601:

> The UTC offset is appended to the time in the same way that 'Z' was
> above, in the form ±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh].

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getFormatedDate(Date date)
    {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+05:30");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
        return df.format(date);
    }
```